# Perform an operation when phone is locked or app is in background

Tags: android, background

A user starts and logs in my app. If there is no user interaction for 15 minutes the user should log out whether the app is in foreground or background. I have used the following code but it is not working when phone is locked or in background:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo
import android.content.Context

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException


object LogOutTimerUtil {
    var longTimer: Timer? = null
    private var TAG = "Hello"
    const val LOGOUT_TIME: Long = 900000 // delay in milliseconds i.e. 5 min = 300000 ms or use timeout argument

    @Synchronized
    fun startLogoutTimer(context: Context?, logOutListener: LogOutListener) {
        if (longTimer != null) {
            longTimer!!.cancel()
            longTimer = null
        }
        if (longTimer == null) {
            longTimer = Timer()
            longTimer!!.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() {
                    cancel()
                    longTimer = null
                    try {
                        val foreGround =
                            ForegroundCheckTask()
                                .execute(context).get()
                        if (foreGround) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "doLogout")
                            logOutListener.doLogout()
                        }
                    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }, LOGOUT_TIME)
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun stopLogoutTimer() {
        if (longTimer != null) {
            longTimer!!.cancel()
            longTimer = null
        }
    }

    interface LogOutListener {
        fun doLogout(){

        }
    }

    internal class ForegroundCheckTask :
        AsyncTask<Context?, Void?, Boolean>() {
        private fun isAppOnForeground(context: Context): Boolean {
            val activityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            val appProcesses =
                activityManager.runningAppProcesses ?: return false
            Log.d(TAG, "runningAppProcesses: ${activityManager.runningAppProcesses}")
            Log.d(TAG, "appProcesses: $appProcesses")
            val packageName: String = context.getPackageName()
            Log.d(TAG, "packageName: $packageName")
            for (appProcess in appProcesses) {
                Log.d(TAG, "1: ${appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND}")
                Log.d(TAG, "2: ${appProcess.processName == packageName}")
                //if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName == packageName) {
                if (appProcess.processName == packageName) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$packageName Running...............")
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Context?): Boolean {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground")
            val context: Context = params[0]!!.getApplicationContext()
            return isAppOnForeground(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On some devices process may be already dead. Singleton (object) is not best approach to handle that.

You may rethink requirements and logout user when app resumes after some time of inactivity, for example persist last interaction time.

Alternatively you can setup AlarmManager job and postpone it with every app interaction onResume/onPause.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please give a reference of AlarmManager?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager